# How to change color in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, fonts

So i am extrating usename and msg from MySQL database and want to change the color of the username and msg.

```
echo "<span class='uname'>" . $extract['username'] . "</span>: <span class='msg'>" . $extract['msg'] . "</span><br>";
```

Comment: you are almost there just add css to it and it's done. What problem are you facing in it ?

Comment: Well whole page is in php and when i add <html> and <style> tags for css it ignores them

Comment: can you provide that code so that we can understand better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo "<span class='uname' style='color: green'>" . $extract['username'] . "</span>: <span class='msg' style='color: blue'>" . $extract['msg'] . "</span><br>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You are better off applying a CSS style to the classes you already have, using a stylesheet in a conventional way, rather than using inline styling, which is unconventional. Although, the inline method is easier. You don't change the color of things in PHP, you do it in CSS. Pick out the colors you want, get the hex codes for them, and then set them as the color or background-color properties depending on how you want to style the username and message.

```
.uname{
    color: #3d3; /* hex values representing Red, Green, Blue */
}
.msg{
    color: #900; /* shorthand for #990000, represents a red hue */
}
```

If you don't have access to the stylesheet for the page, you can include an internal / in-page "stylesheet" with the `style` tag, e.g. put this in the head of the document:

```
<style type="text/css">
.uname{
    color: #3d3; /* hex values representing Red, Green, Blue */
}
.msg{
    color: #900; /* shorthand for #990000, represents a red hue */
}
</style>
```

Example:

```css
.uname, .msg{
  color: #d0d; /* red + blue = some shade of purple */
  background-color: #000; /*red 0, green 0, blue 0 = no color = black*/
}
```

```html
<span class='uname'>" . $extract['username'] . "</span>: <span class='msg'>" . $extract['msg'] . "</span><br>
```